# Jordan and Dynkin quivers

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras, quiver, dynkin-diagrams, kac-moody-algebras

I have a simple question. If I am not wrong, we can define $\tilde{A}_l$ affine Dynkin quiver of type A, for $l\geq1$. It has $l+1$ vertices that we can order from $0$ to $l$ such that $i$ is connected with $i+1$ and $l$ with $0$.

The Jordan quiver is instead a quiver composed by a single vertex and a loop arrow.

So, it makes sense to think a Jordan quiver as "$\tilde{A}_0$". Is this a standard identification? If not, what are problems with that?

Comment: Well there is never any node connected to itself in extended Dynkin diagrams so this doesn't seem like it belongs in the family in a natural way to me.

Comment: We have the ‘affine type A’ diagrams, where $\widetilde A_n$ is an $n$-cycle. Thus the Jordan quiver is $\widetilde A_1$, and the Kronecker quiver is $\widetilde A_2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With respect to the normal numbering $\tilde A_n$ is an $(n+1)$-cycle. In particular, yes, it is reasonable to call the Jordan quiver $\tilde A_0$. See for example chapter 4 of Derksen and Weyman's Introduction to quiver representations, where they do use this notation (at least for the graphs, all they are interested in at that point).